# rails new . does not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4 , up until today I always was able to do `rails new .` and get a project running.

But today when I tried to run it I got

```
/usr/bin/rails:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/potter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

potters-MacBook-Pro:test potter$ rvm list

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I have no idea what changed , any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions to my `/User/<mac username>/.rvm` changed for some reason from 755 to 744. I think it might have to do due to an installation of rjb.

fixed with `chmod`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already have ruby and rails installed in your system (/usr/bin/rails). I think you should clean all current rails and reinstall it from scratch